# React Router - forcing querystring params

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using React Router 3 with hashHistory and I would like my URL structor to use classic query-strings such as '?' and '&' parameters rather than the default '/' ones.

For example I would like to have this:

`http://example.com/#/search?q=term&category=cat&etc=1`

Instead of:

`http://example.com/#/search/term/cat/1`

I am using the following code:

```
<Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/">
        <Route path="/" component={Root} />
        <Route path="/search(/:q)(/:category)" component={SearchContainer} />
    </Route>
</Router>
```

I've tried `<Route path="/search(?:q)(&:category)" component={SearchContainer} />` but I'm receiving undefined in the params object returned from the router.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: What you mean with force?, you just need to set the path as you want. `<Link to="/search?q=term&category=cat&etc=1" />`

Comment: I've rewritten the question because it wasn't very well written...my apologies. My sense now?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to avoid the paths, and use `this.props.location.query` to get the values.
e.g.

```
<Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/">
        <Route path="/" component={Root} />
        <Route path="/search" component={SearchContainer} />
    </Route>
</Router>
```

In SearchContainer:

```
class SearchContainer extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        const q = this.props.location.query; //here you can access the params        
        console.log(q);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I saw this property but I thought it might not be the best to use if I wanted to then use the 'query' property in the Link component. For example: `<Link to="/Search" query={{ q: 'term', category: 'cat' }}>Search</Link>`